# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Transaction'

Tags: transaction, nft, native-assets, blockfrost, native

I am trying to use the https://github.com/Python-Cardano/pycardano/blob/main/examples/native_token.py with minor changes, like pointing to mainnet (have tried preview as well). I have updated the address to point to my actual wallet and trying to create an nft. I am getting the below error

File "\Desktop\CDrive\work\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\pycardano\backend\blockfrost.py", line 230, in submit_tx
self.api.transaction_submit(f.name)
File "\Desktop\CDrive\work\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\blockfrost\utils.py", line 63, in error_wrapper
raise ApiError(request_response)
blockfrost.utils.ApiError: {'error': 'Bad Request', 'message': '"transaction read error RawCborDecodeError [DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure \"Byron Tx\" (DeserialiseFailure 1 \"Size mismatch when decoding TxAux.\\nExpected 2, but found 4.\"),DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure \"Shelley Tx\" (DeserialiseFailure 1 \"Size mismatch when decoding \\nRecord RecD.\\nExpected 4, but found 3.\"),DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure \"Shelley Tx\" (DeserialiseFailure 1 \"Size mismatch when decoding \\nRecord RecD.\\nExpected 4, but found 3.\"),DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure \"Shelley Tx\" (DeserialiseFailure 1 \"Size mismatch when decoding \\nRecord RecD.\\nExpected 4, but found 3.\"),DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure \"Shelley Tx\" (DeserialiseFailure 79 \"expected string\"),DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure \"Shelley Tx\" (DeserialiseFailure 79 \"expected string\")]"', 'status_code': 400}

I am not sure what is wrong, would be of great help if anyone can guide me to get it working. The same code minor change has given have also faced "  File "\Desktop\CDrive\work\Python3.7\lib\tempfile.py", line 481, in func_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Transaction'"

Below is the full python file

"""
This is a complete walk through of minting a NFT on Cardano blockchain in pure Python code.

This example is inspired by https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting-nfts#crafting-the-transaction

import pathlib

from blockfrost import ApiUrls

from pycardano import *

## Copy your BlockFrost project ID below. Go to https://blockfrost.io/ for more information.

BLOCK_FROST_PROJECT_ID = ""
NETWORK = Network.MAINNET

chain_context = BlockFrostChainContext(
project_id=BLOCK_FROST_PROJECT_ID,
base_url=ApiUrls.mainnet.value, #ApiUrls.preprod.value,
)

"""Preparation"""

## Define the root directory where images and keys will be stored.

PROJECT_ROOT = "blockfrost"
root = pathlib.Path(PROJECT_ROOT)
print(PROJECT_ROOT)

## Create the directory if it doesn't exist

root.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

"""Generate keys"""
key_dir = root / "keys"
key_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

## Load payment keys or create them if they don't exist

def load_or_create_key_pair(base_dir, base_name):
skey_path = base_dir / f"{base_name}.skey"
vkey_path = base_dir / f"{base_name}.vkey"

```
if skey_path.exists():
    skey = PaymentSigningKey.load(str(skey_path))
    vkey = PaymentVerificationKey.from_signing_key(skey)
else:
    key_pair = PaymentKeyPair.generate()
    key_pair.signing_key.save(str(skey_path))
    key_pair.verification_key.save(str(vkey_path))
    skey = key_pair.signing_key
    vkey = key_pair.verification_key
return skey, vkey
```

## Payment address. Send some ADA (~5 ADA is enough) to this address, so we can pay the minting fee later.

payment_skey, payment_vkey = load_or_create_key_pair(key_dir, "payment")
address = "<myWalletAddress"

## address = Address(payment_vkey.hash(), network=NETWORK)

```
#"addr_test1qqxypmc96e3pska6ch2ucq4uv5d7uz6nhpgcne4ea4hgmemv40lpm3wmc3wqk5arjpgzrccm0m9k72puaqzwsgrj47asmp86u7" #Address(payment_vkey.hash(), network=NETWORK)
```

print(address)

## Generate policy keys, which will be used when minting NFT

policy_skey, policy_vkey = load_or_create_key_pair(key_dir, "policy")

"""Create policy"""

## A policy that requires a signature from the policy key we generated above

pub_key_policy = ScriptPubkey(policy_vkey.hash())

## A time policy that disallows token minting after 10000 seconds from last block

must_before_slot = InvalidHereAfter(chain_context.last_block_slot + 10000)

## Combine two policies using ScriptAll policy

policy = ScriptAll([pub_key_policy, must_before_slot])

## Calculate policy ID, which is the hash of the policy

policy_id = policy.hash()
print(f"Policy ID: {policy_id}")
with open(root / "policy.id", "a+") as f:
f.truncate(0)
f.write(str(policy_id))
#******************************************************************************************************************************************
"""Define NFT"""

## Create an asset container

my_asset = Asset()

## Create names for our assets

nft1 = AssetName(b"MY_NFT_1")
nft2 = AssetName(b"MY_NFT_2")

## Put assets into the asset container with a quantity of 1

my_asset[nft1] = 1
my_asset[nft2] = 1

## Create a MultiAsset container

my_nft = MultiAsset()

## Put assets into MultiAsset container. In this example, we only have one policy.

## However, MultiAsset container can hold multiple different policies.

my_nft[policy_id] = my_asset

## Create the final native script that will be attached to the transaction

native_scripts = [policy]
#******************************************************************************************************************************************
"""Define NFT (Alternative)"""

## The nft definition above is somewhat verbose.

## We can also directly create native assets from python primitives.

my_nft_alternative = MultiAsset.from_primitive(
{
policy_id.payload: {  # Use policy ID created from above. We can't use policy_id here because policy_id's type  # is ScriptHash, which is not a primitive type. Instead, we use policy_id.payload (bytes)
b"MY_NFT_1": 1,  # Name of our NFT1  # Quantity of this NFT
b"MY_NFT_2": 1,  # Name of our NFT2  # Quantity of this NFT
}
}
)

## my_nft and my_nft_alternative are equivalent

assert my_nft == my_nft_alternative
#******************************************************************************************************************************************
"""Create metadata"""

## We need to create a metadata for our NFTs, so they could be displayed correctly by blockchain explorer

metadata = {
721: {  # 721 refers to the metadata label registered for NFT standard here:
# https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/master/CIP-0010/registry.json#L14-L17
policy_id.payload.hex(): {
"MY_NFT_1": {
"description": "This is my first NFT thanks to PyCardano",
"name": "PyCardano NFT example token 1",
"id": 1,
"image": "ipfs://QmRhTTbUrPYEw3mJGGhQqQST9k86v1DPBiTTWJGKDJsVFw",
},
"MY_NFT_2": {
"description": "This is my second NFT thanks to PyCardano",
"name": "PyCardano NFT example token 2",
"id": 2,
"image": "ipfs://QmRhTTbUrPYEw3mJGGhQqQST9k86v1DPBiTTWJGKDJsVFw",
},
}
}
}

## Place metadata in AuxiliaryData, the format acceptable by a transaction.

auxiliary_data = AuxiliaryData(AlonzoMetadata(metadata=Metadata(metadata)))

"""Build transaction"""

## Create a transaction builder

builder = TransactionBuilder(chain_context)

## Add our own address as the input address

builder.add_input_address(address)

## Since an InvalidHereAfter rule is included in the policy, we must specify time to live (ttl) for this transaction

builder.ttl = must_before_slot.after

## Set nft we want to mint

builder.mint = my_nft

## Set native script

builder.native_scripts = native_scripts

## Set transaction metadata

builder.auxiliary_data = auxiliary_data

## Calculate the minimum amount of lovelace that need to hold the NFT we are going to mint

min_val = min_lovelace(
chain_context, output=TransactionOutput(address, Value(0, my_nft))
)

## Send the NFT to our own address

builder.add_output(TransactionOutput(address, Value(min_val, my_nft)))

## Create final signed transaction

signed_tx = builder.build_and_sign([payment_skey], change_address=address)

## signed_tx = builder.build_and_sign([payment_skey, policy_skey], change_address=address)

print("############### Transaction created ###############")
print("------------------------------Signed transaction------------------------------")
print(signed_tx)
print("-------------------------------------Signed to CBOR------------------------------")
print(signed_tx.to_cbor())

## Submit signed transaction to the network

print("############### Submitting transaction ###############")

chain_context.submit_tx(signed_tx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error stems from the `chain_context.submit_tx(signed_tx)` because the API expects CBOR encoded transaction (couple lines above).

You might want to try

`chain_context.submit_tx(signed_tx.to_cbor())`